# visual basic regex mode/pattern modifier

Tags: php, asp.net, regex, vb.net

I ran into a trouble.
I'm currently testing the regex in PHP (not in my ASP.NET app, as long as it takes me a while)

```
$pattern = '~<table.*>(.*?)</table>~s';
```

I need to convert this line into VB format. Including 's' modifier (at the end of the regex)

I doubt it this code covers what I need

```
Dim TableExpression = "<table.*>(.*?)</table>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many flavors give you the option of putting the modifiers in the regex itself, like so:

```
Dim TableExpression = "(?s)<table.*>(.*?)</table>"
```

`(?s)` is called an *inline modifier*, and you can read about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).  It works in most of the major languages, including .NET and PHP.  The most notable holdout is JavaScript, which is incredibly frustrating because it means you can't do case-insensitive matches in an ASP.NET validator unless you disable client-side validation.